# Litespeed frame has clear film all over it

Tags: cleaning, titanium

I never noticed the film on my Ti frame until it started peeling. What is this? Can I safely remove it? It seems to be flaking off on its own anyway.

Comment: Did you try to ask Litespeed?

Comment: Since Ti does not oxydize except under high temperature there is no reason to leave it on.

Comment: @Carel. Actually, like aluminum, titanium is already oxidized under ambient conditions (https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Pourbaix-diagram-for-titanium-at-37C_fig4_26620547). However, the oxide layer is very thin and prevents further oxidation of the metal. This is one of the reasons why welding it properly is so difficult.

Comment: How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1):

If it’s polished Ti (bright silver) it’s most likely the protective clear coat finish. A picture would help confirm that.

If the bike is relatively new contact Litespeed and see if they will cover it under warrantee.

Comment: It isn't covered under warrantee anymore, but it seems like I don't really need it?